# Right invertible element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is as follows:
$a,b \in L$ where $L$ is a ring.
We are given that $ab=1$.

I need to prove or disprove that $a$ is invertible (meaning, there is an element $x \in L : ax=xa=1$).

But how can we say that for sure? just because $ab=1$ doesn't mean that $ba=1$, ba could be something else altogether, we werent given that this is a commutative ring.

Please give advice on how to solve, thank you.

Word by word translation of the question to make it clearer:
Prove or disprove that if $a$ and $b$ are elements of $L$ and $ab=1$, then $a$ is invertible.

Comment: You didn't quantify whether this was for all $a$ there exists a $b$ such that $ab = 1$. Is that what you mean? This makes it evident it is invertible (it is the def'n).

Comment: I'll quote the question word by word: prove or disprove that if a and b are elements of L and ab=1 then a is invertible.

Comment: Admitting an inverse. An object that is invertible is referred to as an invertible element in a monoid or a unit ring, or to a map, which admits an inverse map iff it is bijective. This means it has a left and right inverse in the inverse part, if that is what you are asking @OriaGruber

Comment: Yes, indeed, @nik ! I wanted to delete my answer but since Oria started a dialogue about it I'll leave my post (also because I wrote a comment on some students' reaction to certain similar examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $L$ is the ring of $\mathbb R$-linear maps  $l:\mathbb R[X]\to \mathbb R[X]$ (with multiplication being composition).
Consider $D,I\in L$ defined by $D(P(X))=P'(X)$ and $I(P(X))=\int _0^XP(t)dt$.
Then $D\circ I=Id$ but nevertheless $D$ is not invertible because...

Comment: Because I (composition) D is not the identity transformation?

Comment: Yes. Or because $D$ is not injective: $D(r)=0$ for all constant polynomials $r\in \mathbb R\subset \mathbb R[X]$

Comment: By the way, could you complete the equality $I(D(P(X)))=?$ , in other words compute $I\circ D$ ?

Comment: My students are often puzzled by this kind of example because it mixes linear algebra and calculus. Have  teachers on this site had the same reaction from some of their students?

Comment: I'm not sure I (composition) D is a function, since it can have many images for the same source. for example the polynomial 2x can go to 2x or 2x+1 or 2x-1...I(D(2x)) = I(2) = 2x+c, c is an element of R

Comment: Dear Oria, no: $I$ is not any old antiderivative but **the** antiderivative  which vanishes when $X=0$. So $I(2)=\int _0^X 2dt=2X$ and not $I(2)=2X+1$, which is false.

Comment: in that case why isn't I*D identity? can you give an example where I(D(P(X))) is not P(X)?

Comment: Here is an example: $(I\circ D)(2X+1)=I(2)=2X$, so $I\circ D\neq Id$

Comment: That's right! I should have thought of that. Thank you Georges you have helped me a lot and I understood what you said and the examples you gave. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, dear Oria, and I'm very happy that I could help you understand these rather subtle concepts.